# How can you define a variable that can hold one of a specific set of closure signatures?

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, swift4

Consider the below code.  It lets you instantiate a processor by passing in a closure that can handle a payload.  The closure can be one of six signature types.  Here's how I have it implemented:

I'm wondering if there's a simpler/better way to write this.  I'm thinking perhaps by using enums with associated values, but that means I'd have to wrap the closure in the enum, then pass the enum to the initializer.  I'm hoping to avoid that if possible.

```
struct Payload {
    let stringVal : String
    let intVal    : Int
}

class Processor{

    init(action:Any){

        switch action {
            case let action as ()       -> Void,
                 let action as ()       -> Error?,
                 let action as (String) -> Void,
                 let action as (String) -> Error?,
                 let action as (Int)    -> Void,
            case let action as (Int)    -> Error?,
            default: fatalError("Action does not have a supported signature")
        }

        self.action = action
    }

    let action:Any

    func performAction(payload:Payload) -> Error? {

        switch action {

            case let action as () -> Void:
                action()

            case let action as () -> Error?:
                return action()

            case let action as (String) -> Void:
                action(payload.stringVal)

            case let action as (String) -> Error?:
                return action(payload.stringVal)

            case let action as (Int) -> Void:
                action(payload.intVal)

            case let action as (Int) -> Error?:
                return action(payload.intVal)

            default: fatalError("Action does not have a supported signature")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Also, in the initializer where I'm performing the pattern-matching to determine if I have a valid match, I get a compiler warning saying I've set, but never used `action`.  However, if I instead replace it with `_`, I then get a warning that I'm not binding to anything in the pattern. How can I suppress the warning while also performing a test for the pattern where I don't care what the value is?

Comment: I think an enum with associated types would be the proper way to go.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I keep coming back to as well.  But if I go that route, is there any way to still pass `Any` to the initializer and map to the correct enum inside?  I ask because the enum technically makes no sense outside of the function with the sole exception of giving the initializer a wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using parameters of type `Any`. Use an enum with associated types:

```
enum Action {
    case a1(() -> Void)
    case a2(() -> Error?)
    case a3((String) -> Void)
    case a4((String) -> Error?)
    case a5((Int) -> Void)
    case a6((Int) -> Error?)
}

struct Payload {
    let stringVal : String
    let intVal    : Int
}

class Processor{
    let action: Action

    init(action: Action) {
        self.action = action
    }

    func performAction(payload: Payload) -> Error? {
        var error: Error? = nil
        switch action {
        case let .a1(closure):
            closure()
        case let .a2(closure):
            error = closure()
        case let .a3(closure):
            closure(payload.stringVal)
        case let .a4(closure):
            error = closure(payload.stringVal)
        case let .a5(closure):
            closure(payload.intVal)
        case let .a6(closure):
            error = closure(payload.intVal)
        }

        return error
    }
}
```

This ensures that you can only pass valid actions to your Payload class.

There needs to be a better naming convention for the Action case values but this will get you started.

Here's an example of the usage:

```
let payload = Payload(stringVal: "Hello", intVal: 42)
let myAction = {
    print("Working")
}
let action = Action.a1(myAction)
let processor = Processor(action: action)
let error = processor.performAction(payload: payload)
```

Another way is to make `Action` internal to `Processor` and provide `Processor` with 6 initializers.

```
struct Payload {
    let stringVal : String
    let intVal    : Int
}

class Processor{
    enum Action {
        case a1(() -> Void)
        case a2(() -> Error?)
        case a3((String) -> Void)
        case a4((String) -> Error?)
        case a5((Int) -> Void)
        case a6((Int) -> Error?)
    }

    private let action: Action

    init(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = .a1(closure)
    }

    init(_ closure: @escaping () -> Error?) {
        self.action = .a2(closure)
    }

    init(_ closure: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        self.action = .a3(closure)
    }

    init(_ closure: @escaping (String) -> Error?) {
        self.action = .a4(closure)
    }

    init(_ closure: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        self.action = .a5(closure)
    }

    init(_ closure: @escaping (Int) -> Error?) {
        self.action = .a6(closure)
    }

    func performAction(payload: Payload) -> Error? {
        var error: Error? = nil
        switch action {
        case let .a1(closure):
            closure()
        case let .a2(closure):
            error = closure()
        case let .a3(closure):
            closure(payload.stringVal)
        case let .a4(closure):
            error = closure(payload.stringVal)
        case let .a5(closure):
            closure(payload.intVal)
        case let .a6(closure):
            error = closure(payload.intVal)
        }

        return error
    }
}

let payload = Payload(stringVal: "Hello", intVal: 42)
let myAction = {
    print("Working")
}
let processor = Processor(myAction)
let error = processor.performAction(payload: payload)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I keep leaning towards because unlike my solution, this can be validated at compile-time. However, I think rather than an initializer that takes the enum wrapping the function, I'm going to create six initializers, one per signature, then internally use the enum.  That way the outside world doesn't even need to know about it.  If you update your answer to that approach, I'll mark it as accepted rather than answering it myself (not that you need the points! lol)

Comment: I was just updating the answer with an example. I suppose the `Action` enum could be moved inside the `Processor` class and `Processor` could be updated to have 6 initializers to hide any use of `Action` from the caller.

Comment: That's precisely what I just said in the comment.  I think that's a cleaner interface, no?  Then no one on the outside needs to know about the enum. It becomes part of the 'black box'.  Then again, if you go that route, why not just have six optional member variables, each representing a type? Then you can if-let unwrap them and if you got it, call it.  That too would give you type-safety, just like the enums, but wouldn't require the enum. Thoughts?

Comment: Right, I was simply agreeing with you.

Comment: Thoughts on the six private optional member vars instead of the enum?